# Remove Visual Editor and P tags from WooCommerce Taxonomy Descriptions

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

WooCommerce: Products >  Categories/Tags/Brands > Description.

1. By default visual editor is enabled. How do you disable that to be only a basic text area only?

Most threads here seem to be on 'adding' the editor so assuming at some point WP or WooCommerce added the editor by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope,  The following code solve your problem. Add this in functions.php

```
$tags = $_GET['taxonomy'];
$taxonomy_name = array('product_tag','product_cat');
if (in_array($tags, $taxonomy_name)) {
  add_action("{$tags}_edit_form_fields", 'form_fields', 10, 2);
}
function form_fields($term, $taxonomy){
    ?>
    <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row">Description</th>
        <td>
            <?php wp_editor(html_entity_decode($term->description), 'description', array('media_buttons' => false,'quicktags' => false)); ?>
            <style>
              .js .tmce-active .wp-editor-area{
                color:black !important;
              }
            </style>
            <script>
                jQuery(window).ready(function(){
                    jQuery('label[for=description]').parent().parent().remove();
                });
            </script>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much very helpful! So when editing an actual say category description its working as expected, except the text is white. For some reason it's calling this core css line: .js .tmce-active .wp-editor-area{color:#fff}; More importantly, on the main category/tag listing page a visual editor appears randomly at the top of the page above the title, "Product Categories" and sort of breaks the backend.

Comment: Ok i am updating my code.

Comment: @cchiera answer is updated. Hope this solution perfectly work for you. Let me know if you face any trouble. Thanks

Comment: @faysal-mahmud That worked! Thanks so much.